# Powershell : convert API output in a table format

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to extract data from API using the command below

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://xxx.ccxx.com/IDORequestService/MGRestService.svc/json/SLCos/RowPointer,CustNum/adv/' -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

The output is then
[image]

I now need to extract that data in either a csv file or send it in table to a SQL table. Ideally the later. How could I achieve this? The output from the API is in JSON format.

Comment: Look up [format-table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table).

Comment: can't understand how to use it

Comment: Start with: [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How is this not a good question? I have so many things but can't get it to work. I thought of getting it out of csv and the output is csv is worse.

Comment: "How is this not a good question?" Read that article to get the answer.

Comment: If you really don't understand how to use format-table, read [about pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines).

Comment: @vonPryz, `Format-Table` alone won't help here: the output _is_ already tabular, but it is in the form of key-value pairs, whereas I presume the intent is to have the keys as the table column headers and the values as the column data.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that `$response.Items` contains an array of (ordered) `[hashtable]` instances**, you can take advantage of PowerShell's ability to cast a hashtable to `[pscustomobject]`, which, with 4 or fewer properties, *implicitly* results in tabular output (but you can always pipe to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)).

```
# With 4 or fewer entries per hashtable in $response.Items,
# you get tabular output by default; otherwise, pipe to Format-Table
$response.Items | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] $_ }
```

**The resulting array of `[pscustomobject]` instances - objects with *properties* (rather than hashtables with *entries*) - can easily be processed further**, such as with the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet.

If you originally obtained `$response` via [`ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), consider omitting `-AsHashTable` in order to get (nested) `[pscustomobject]` instances *directly*, assuming the JSON data allows it (no empty-string keys, no properties on a given object whose names differ by case only).

---

**A simple example**:

An array of hashtables outputs key-value pairs, which only ever outputs two columns with fixed names, `Name` and `Value`:

```
PS> @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, @{ one = 10; two = 20 }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
one                            1
two                            2
one                            10
two                            20
```

By casting the hashtables to `[pscustomobject]`, the (implicitly tabular) output now uses the actual key names as the column headers, and the corresponding values as the column data:

Note:

- This only works as expected if all input hashtables have the same keys; otherwise, the first hashtable's keys lock in all output columns and only they are shown, whether or not later hashtables have different keys.
- For brevity, the built-in alias `%` is used for [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)

```
PS> @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, @{ one = 10; two = 20 } | % { [pscustomobject] $_ }

one two
--- ---
  1   2
 10  20
```

To demonstrate that the resulting array of `[pscustomobject]` instances can easily be processed by other cmdlets, using the example of [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv):

```
PS> @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, @{ one = 10; two = 20 } | % { [pscustomobject] $_ } |
      ConvertTo-Csv

"one","two"
"1","2"
"10","20"
```